# Multiple drivers on a single objects x rotation

Tags: animation, drivers

I am working on a project that needs each of six arms to respond to more than one input.  I used several bones to accomplish this with the first driving a cube's rotation and each subsequent bone driving the x rotation of the first bone. Results is each bone rotates the cube's x rotation. I have the .blend of the test file at: brokensky.biz/blendfiles/drivertest.blend

My question is: Is there a simpler way to do this? Can multiple objects or bones affect a single driver?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can go the "Drivers" way. Using multiple variable as input (one per bone) and adding them together to get what you want.
Here is more detail about how to use Drivers in blender :
https://blender.org/manual/animation/basics/drivers.html

Here is an example from your blend : 
http://www.pasteall.org/blend/38396